# Need field on Contact to display associated user profile name?

Tags: apex

Need field on Contact to display associated user profile name?

We need a field on Contact to display its associated user profile. What is best way of doing this in salesforce?

Comment: Each `User` object has a single related `Profile` object. A Salesforce Customer Portal setup has a one to one relationship between `User` and `Contact` but otherwise there is normally no direct relationship between these two objects. Can you provide more detail in your question? What do you mean by "its associated user profile"?

Comment: Firstly each Contact is associated with single user. And User has related Profile object as you mentioned. Now I want to have a field on contact to display its associated user profile name. For Ex., Contact A has Associated with User 'AA' and this  'AA' user has profile named 'HHHH'. Now i want to show field which displays 'HHHH" on Contact object.

Comment: The 1:1 relationship in the Customer Portal setup uses a User.ContactId field and roll-up summaries can't be used. So you are stuck with writing triggers on User (and Profile) that copy the Profile name to a new field that you add on Contact when that association changes (or the Profile name changes).

Comment: I'm assuming you need this because of a customer community implementation. If so, I'd add a custom field done as a look-up on User. Having done a customer community, I understand the need you likely have. I recall initially needing to add extra queries to triggers to get User Profiles for Contacts. How you implement your security model, can also affect whether or not this is really necessary. We later learned we could bypass the need for handling security thru Portal Users for a customer contact by using a different sharing model than we began with.